# Reference queue in another .c

Tags: c

Im working with the TI Z-Stack znp-project and implement a own functions in a separate file (`bc.c` + `bc.h`). Although I'm fresh to C I managed all fine except one thing:

in the file `znp_app.c` I need to reference a queue for uart-tx-ing:

```
static osal_msg_q_t npTxQueue;
```

to achieve what I now wrote in the `znp_app.c` in my own `bc.c` (where I include `znp_app.h`).

```
void bc_sendResponse(...)  // in bc.c
{
    ...
    npSendForBc(bcMSGp);   // want to call "osal_msg_enqueue(&npTxQueue, pBuf);" here
    ...
}

void npSendForBc(uint8 *pBuf)  // workaround function in znp_app.c
{
    osal_msg_enqueue(&npTxQueue, pBuf); // need this in bc.c
}
```

I tried to define the queue in the `znp_app.h`, but the compiler don't appreciates it. 
I also tried do write some kind of "getter", but it also was not supported. 
Please show me the correct syntax, ty.

**EDIT 1**

I already tried to

```
extern osal_msg_q_t npTxQueue; // in znp_app.h
```

but I get this error while linking:

```
error: Error[e46]: Undefined external "npTxQueue" referred in bc ( C:\...\Z-Stack 3.0.1\Projects\zstack\ZNP\CC253x\CC2531-ZNP-with-SBL\Obj\bc.r51 )
```

As getter I tried (with an extern in `znp_app.h`)

```
osal_msg_q_t getQueues()
{
    return npTxQueue;
}
```

I cant exactly remember the error code.

Comment: That the variable is marked as `static` is a way to make it "private", which means you should never need to use the variable in another source file. If you do, then you probably have a flaw in your design.

Comment: "*I also tried do write some kind of "getter", but it also was not supported*" could you elaborate a bit more on this? What does "not supported" mean?

Comment: @alk I edited my question, but i cant exactly remember the error and think its a no-c-way^^

Comment: You still have the code, right? Build again and it'll give you the same error.

Comment: "*i cant exactly remember the error*" Then what about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_notebook) though ...? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `npTxQueue` an ugly global:

- Put into `znp_app.h`

  ```
  extern osal_msg_q_t npTxQueue;
  ```
- and into `znp_app.c` put (without any `static`)

  ```
  osal_msg_q_t npTxQueue;
  ```
- and include into `znp_app.c` `znp_app.h` as well (before the definition of `npTxQueue`).
- Finally include `znp_app.h` into where you need `npTxQueue`.

---

Alternativly use a getter by

- moving the definition of  `osal_msg_q_t` to `znp_app.h` (if not in there already).
- and add (below the definition of  `osal_msg_q_t`) the prototype of the getter to `znp_app.h` as well:

  ```
  osal_msg_q_t GetIt(void);
  ```
- and add the getter's implementation to `znp_app.c`:

  ```
  osal_msg_q_t GetIt(void)
  {
    return npTxQueue; 
  }
  ```
- Finally include `znp_app.h` into where you need `npTxQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

Static in a global scope means it is only visible in that file. You're confusing it with static in a function I suspect. See this answer for details:

[What does "static" mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c#572550)

A global variable is implicitly the same as a static variable in a function, you don't need the static at the global scope in your code. You will then also want to define the variable using the extern keyword in your header file, as per:

[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files#1433387)

Comment: I tried (and now again) (put in .h with extern and without static) but i get this error:
Error[e46]: Undefined external "npTxQueue" referred in bc ( C:\...\Z-Stack 3.0.1\Projects\zstack\ZNP\CC253x\CC2531-ZNP-with-SBL\Obj\bc.r51 ) on "make" while compile says no errors